# Perpendicular form of the straight line equation in n-dimensional space

Tags: analytic-geometry

A similar question was discussed before but it was in a 2-dimensional space.
[Perpendicular form of the straight line equation.](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/740334/627145)
So how can the derivation in a 2D space be generalized to an n-dimensional space? In other words, how can we derive the perpendicular form of a specific line perpendicular to the hyperplane defined as L = A.X1 + B.X2+ C.X3 + ... + K.Xn in an n-dimensional space?

Comment: In spaces with more than two dimensions what you call perpendicular form becomes a system of equations.

Comment: A line in more than two dimensions can’t be represented by a single implicit linear Cartesian equation.

Comment: Thanks a lot. So how about the directions of the hyperplane? What do the cosine directions derived from L's equation represent in the n-dimensional space? And can those directions be used to derive a new coordinate system which is parallel to the hyperplane L in some direction (similar to a rotation in 2D)? I would also appreciate if you recommend me some references on this regard.

Answer (score 0):

The vector ${\bf A}=(A_1,A_2, \cdots, A_n)$ is a vector normal to the plane.

Denoting by $\bf X$ the generic point of coordinates $(x_1,\cdots, x_n)$
and by $\bf P$ a given point, then
 $${\bf(X-P)}=\lambda \bf A$$
is the parametric equation of a line normal to the plane, and passing through $\bf P$.

Comment: Thanks for your comment. In this sense, can we derive the angles between the normal vector A and the axes of the coordinate system using the above equation similarly to the 2D case (alpha in this answer: https://math.stackexchange.com/a/740382/627145)?

Comment: @Mr.Gulliver: Yes, provided that you take the normalized vector ${\bf A}/{|\bf A|}$, whose components will be the cosines of the angles that the line makes with each axis.

Comment: @G Cab Thank you!